# Gapi auth2 is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-js-client

I'm useing this code

```
gpLogIn() {;
window['gapi'].auth2.authorize({
  client_id: 'xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  scope: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
  ].join(' '),
  response_type: 'id_token permission',
  'prompt': 'select_account',
}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

}

But my auth2 is undefined. Should I call something more, before calling my signIn method?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not finding Google, then I would guess you have forgotten to include the library.

```
<script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>


 /**
 * Callback after Google Identity Services is loaded.
 */
function gisLoaded() {
    tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        callback: '', // defined later
    });
    gisInited = true;
    maybeEnableButtons();
}
```